# Formatting windows 8 partition without loosing data on ubuntu

Tags: windows, format

How to format Windows 8 with dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 without loosing my data on Ubuntu? Can I change the size of partition for each OS too?

Comment: Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community! This question has not been done any real research on. Make sure you cannot find the answer elsewhere before asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you currently have two separate petitions, one for each OS, then you can format the Windows 8 partition without loss of data on the Ubuntu partition. You can do this through Ubuntu or during the Windows install.

The easiest way to change the size of your partition is with LVM.